# Writing Numbering to adjacent cell according to color

Tags: google-apps-script

Using this script which writes the color numbering in a sequence for the all colored cell except the default one.

I want to write value for the default color as well so i can sort it later.

But it should not write the value for the those rows which are empty but it is writing values for the empty row as well.

any help will be appreciated.

```
function numberColors4() {
  
  var colorCol = 1,     
      numberCol = 11,    
      firstDataRow = 2, 

      palette = [
        "#ffffff",  // Default 1
        "#ff9900",  // Orange 2
        "#00b0f0", // Light Blue 3
        "#ffff00", // yellow 4 
        "#93c47d", // Green 5
        "#00ff00", // Light Green 6
        "#9900ff", // Purple 7
        "#ff0000", // Red 8
        "#5f5f5f" // Grey 9     
      ];

  var numbers = [],
      activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1')

      dataNumRows = activeSheet.getMaxRows()-(firstDataRow-1),
      colorColColors = activeSheet.getRange(2, colorCol, dataNumRows, 1).getBackgrounds();

  for (var rowIndex in colorColColors) {
    numbers[rowIndex] = [];

    var rowColor = colorColColors[rowIndex].toString(),
        colorIndex = palette.indexOf(rowColor);

    if (colorIndex == -1) {
      numbers[rowIndex].push(rowColor); 

    } else if (colorIndex == 0) {
      numbers[rowIndex].push(""); 

    } else {
      numbers[rowIndex].push(colorIndex);
    }
  }
  activeSheet.getRange(2, numberCol, dataNumRows, 1).setValues(numbers);

}
```

Comment: I'd advice to add a couple sreenshots: what you have for now, and what you want to have. Look, the suggested answer does some job and provide right direction. But it obviously returns quite different results. So it makes sense to show how your desired results should look like.

Comment: Hi thank you for commenting @Yuri Khristich you are right the below answer is pasting the color code instead of Numbering. I need the Numering `1 for "#ffffff"` then `2 for "#ff9900"` and so on. So later i will sort them Small to large. In the same squence as available in the above script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will output the background color if the color is on the palette and the cell is not empty:

```js
function numberColors4(){
  var colorCol = 1;
  var numberCol = 11;
  var firstDataRow = 2;


  var palette = [
    "#ffffff",  // Default 
    "#ff9900",  // Orange 8
    "#00b0f0", // Light Blue 1
    "#ffff00", // yellow 4 
    "#93c47d", // Green 7
    "#00ff00", // Light Green 5
    "#9900ff", // Purple 6
    "#ff0000", // Red 3
    "#5f5f5f" // Grey 2     
  ];

  var numbers = [];
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dataNumRows = activeSheet.getMaxRows()-(firstDataRow-1);
  var colorColColors = activeSheet.getRange(2, colorCol, dataNumRows, 1).getBackgrounds();
  var colorColTexts = activeSheet.getRange(2, colorCol, dataNumRows, 1).getValues();

  for (var rowIndex=0; rowIndex<colorColColors.length; rowIndex++){

    var rowColor = colorColColors[rowIndex].toString();
    var rowText = colorColTexts[rowIndex].toString();

    if (palette.includes(rowColor) && rowText != ""){
      numbers.push([palette.indexOf(rowColor)]);
    }
    else{
      numbers.push([""]);
    }
  }
  activeSheet.getRange(2, numberCol, dataNumRows, 1).setValues(numbers);
}
```

### Main Changes

- Apart from the **colorColColors**, it is also grabbing the texts (**colorColTexts) inside the cells with the [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) method.
- There is only one **if** statement: it checks whether the background color of the cell is inside the palette and that the cell is not empty. If the conditions are met, the color code will be written into the spreadsheet. If either of those fail, an empty string will be written into the spreadsheet.

Comment: Thank you @Oriol Castander for the answer you answer is perfectly working but i need numbering in the same sequence as available in the Appscript. I need the Numering `1 for "#ffffff"` then `2 for "#ff9900"` and so on. So later i will sort them Small to large.

Comment: Changed the code to reflect that. Now using **indexOf** to fetch the index of that color in the palette array.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to make it to work for ActiveSheet insterad of specific.